# Reading attribute string from child nodes using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

Im having trouble reading attribute strings while using XmlDocument to read thro child nodes.
To be more specific, im trying to read an XML containing a list of running processes:

```
<Process_List>
  <Processes>
    <ibmpmsvc ID_1="860" />
    <svchost ID_2="8616" />
    <chrome ID_4="4300" />
    <SearchIndexer ID_5="3868" />
    <smss ID_6="416" />
  </processes>
</Process_List>
```

Each start element presents a running process along with its ID (and some other stuff later on).

So Im using XmlDocument to read thro each child node of /Process_List/Processes:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Process_List/Processes");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    XmlNodeList cxnList = xn.ChildNodes;
    foreach (XmlNode child in cxnList)
    {
        listProc1.Add(child.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

Problem is, Im only getting the child's name, (ibmpmsvc, svchost , chrome) and can't figure out how to get its other attributes.

thanks!

Comment: Tried Child.attribute ??

Comment: What do you want to add to listProc1? Concatenated string? And why you can't use Linq to Xml?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`child.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.attributes.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the the XMLNode C# Class for an overview of what properties are available to you : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx

```
listProc1.Add(child.Name.ToString());
```

Will only give you the Name of the element, which is what you are receiving. You need to also look at the `.Value` property and `.Attributes` (which in turn can be Enumerated through).